# Get an attribute value of touchableOpacity tag onPress in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new in react native I have a question. I want to create my own picker.
So I tried to list my Items one by one in a TouchableOpacity so when user touched an item I can get it's value.

```
<TouchableOpacity key={12} lable='12' style={{margin:3}} onPress={() => this._helloXP(this.key)} >
```

How can I achive this?
is there a way to get an attributes value of a tag by pressing?
in above example I want to get key and lable value by pressing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already creating a function for every `onPress`, you can just pass those props to the function.

`<TouchableOpacity style={{margin:3}} onPress={() => this._helloXP(12, '12')} >`